# Solution to insert data from textarea to database

Tags: javascript, php, database, insert, wysiwyg

I am programming a new website which add topics to database.

I made input for title and textarea for content and I use wysiwyg editor with the textarea to add some effects to my articles.

The problem is that when I try to insert data to db it fails to insert the content of textarea and when I remove the wysiwyg it works perfectly.

I am using is PHP and i use jQuery to insert data without refreshing the page.

This is the code i am using===>

**ajax.js**

```
$('#share').click(function(){
var title=$("#tilearticle").val();
if(title== ''){$('#tiart').show('slow');}
else{
var datastring= $("#form1").serialize();
var url1='action.php?action=article';
$.post(url1,datastring,function(info){$("#res").html(info);});
}
  });
```

**action.php**

```
 if($_GET['action']=='article'){
$get=$_GET['action'];
$title=$_POST['title']; // get data from title input
$content=$_POST['ckeditor1']; // get data from textarea
$image=$_POST['image'];
$date=date("Y/m/d");
$newtitle=string_limit_words($title, 6);
$urltitle=preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i',' ', $newtitle);
$newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$newtitle);
$url='/'.$newurltitle.'.html';
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO article (id,title,img,content,url,time ) VALUES 
              ('','".$title."','".$image."','".$content."','".$url."','".$date."')") or         die(mysql_error());
if($sql){
echo 'work';}else{echo 'nooo';}
}
```

**add.php** // add article page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='action.php?action=article' method='post'   id='form1' role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">title</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name='title' id="tilearticle" placeholder="title">
  <span id='tiart'style='color:red;display: none;'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'> </i> pleas fill in the field</span>
</div>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
     <textarea class="form-control ckeditor" name='ckeditor1' id='textarea' rows="4">  </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
   <input type="file" name="image"id="filearticle">

   <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
 </div> ';

  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <button type="button" name='submit' id='share' class="btn btn-default">Post</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You do not perform any validation, your code is vunerable to SQL injection, and you use deprecated mysql_* functions. If you are aware of that and your code is just for llearning purposes then `addslashes($date)` will probably solve your problem. Or rather cover it, because as  mentioned, your code is not safe.

Comment: @coder can you give me example i am new in php

Comment: @MarkS the script is just to learn and improve my skills and i am aware of the risks. my question is just is there a way to insert data to db without removing wysiwyg

Comment: First of all, with wyswig, before query try `echo $content` - is it empty? If not, does it have characters that need to be escaped (i.e. '). In your query you can try escaping with `addslashes($content)` it will eventually escape your text.

Comment: @MarkS i try to print $content befor query but its empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable that before inserting into the DB, you should always escape with

```
addslashes($value)
```